# Prolog String manipulation, replacing part of string

Tags: string, prolog

What i am trying to do

```
?- string_manipulation(1\2\3,Z).
Z = 1/2/3.
?- string_manipulation(s/t/a/c/k,Z).
Z = s\t\a\c\k.
```

What i have tried so far

```
sign(/,\).
string_manipulation(Forward,Back):-
         sign(Forward,_\),  

; sign(/,Back).
```

I will be honest with you. I know this code is rubbish. I am kinda lost with this one. Just started learning Prolog, watched some videos and read some documentation but could not just find something similar to that from internet in the first look. Maybe someone could point me in some direction so i could learn the string manipulation with this one.

Comment: Got some new idea, maybe i should take this Forward or Back and convert it to a list. Change symbols in it and then convert to the output. How it sounds?

Comment: That definitely sounds like a plan. **Atoms** and lists of **characters** may fit your task. You can start with an atom, use **`atom_chars/2`** to convert it to a list of **characters**, then use a relation that describes what a replacement means for each of these characters (check out `maplist/3` to lift such a definition to lists of characters), then use `atom_chars/2` (again) to obtain again an atom.  This stays very readable throughout the whole program. On the other hand (preferable), you can also work on the plain term representation, replacing `/(A,B)` with `\(A,B)` throughout.

Comment: How this plain term representation throughout works?

Comment: You are already using it: Try out yourself what the term looks like in prefix notation (instead of infix), using `write_canonical/1` in conforming systems such as GNU Prolog. `?- write_canonical(s/t/a/c/k).` for example yields: `/(/(/(/(s,t),a),c),k)`. From this, you see what this term looks like, and you can easily write a Prolog predicate that relates such terms to terms that use a different functor instead of `(/)/2`. If such terms already appear in your code, this is preferable because it retains the actual structure of your terms and only exchanges the functor.

Answer (score 1):

From the post title, and the predicate name (so called functor), seems you're looking for something like DCGs, but as an exercise in manipulation of structured terms, and operators, here is a solution for your probem:

```
string_manipulation(Xs, Ys) :-
    member(( Xo , Yo ), [ ( / , \ ), ( \ , / ) ]),
    Xs =.. [Xo, H, Xt],
    Ys =.. [Yo, T, Yt],
    string_manipulation(H, T),
    string_manipulation(Xt, Yt).
string_manipulation(S, S) :-
    atomic(S).
```

In SWI-Prolog, we need this preliminary declaration:

```
?- op(400,yfx,\).
true.
```

since by default

```
?- current_op(X,Y,/).
X = 400,
Y = yfx.
```

and

```
?- current_op(X,Y,\).
X = 200,
Y = fy.
```

Declaring the same precedence and associativity helps to keep things clearer.

*Edit*

The valuable suggestion by @mat:

```
string_manipulation(Xs, Ys) :-
    op_replacement(Xo, Yo),
    Xs =.. [Xo, H, Xt],
    ...
```

and

```
op_replacement(/, \).
op_replacement(\, /).
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you want to replace an atom in an atom by another atom. But you would need to place quotes around the arguments, like for example '1\2\3' instead 1\2\3, otherwise the argument is not an atom but a term.

If your Prolog system has atom_split/3, you can bootstrap atom_replace/4 from it. [atom_split/3](http://prolog-commons.org/PrologCommons.html/atoms.html) is part of Prolog Commons, and you need a bidrectional version of it. Namely you can then define:

```
atom_replace(Source, Old, New, Target) :-
    atom_split(Source, Old, List),
    atom_split(Target, New, List).
```

Here are some example runs. Don't worry about the backslash backslash, that is just needed to input an atom that contains a backslash. The second example using write/1 shows that it will not enter the atom:

```
Jekejeke Prolog 3, Runtime Library 1.3.6

?- atom_replace('1\\2\\3', '\\', '/', X).
X = '1/2/3'

?- atom_replace('s/t/a/c/k', '/', '\\', X), write(X), nl.
s\t\a\c\k
X = 's\\t\\a\\c\\k'
```